# simpleimagecheckbox vertical align

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

Hi I am using a jquery pluguin called simpleimagecheck that replaces the checkbox by an image but the text alongside is not middle aligned. i tried

```
input[type=checkbox]
{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

doesnt work, if anyone could help that would be great

Comment: Can you post the markup for this checkbox image and the text beside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are saying this plugin replaces the check box by an image then this css will not be applied. Use a class name or by tag as per the markup that is generated.